# Match groups inside 2 parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, match

I'm having a tough time getting this to work. I have a string like:

((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((e and f and h) and not (c and d)) or ((h and i) and not (k and d)) ......

What I need is to match the string above and capture text between each two parentheses ((my group)) like:

- Group 1: ((a and b) and not (c and d))
- Group 2: ((e and f and h) and not (c and d))
- Group 3: (c and d)) or ((h and i) and not (k and d))

And separated with 'or' operator.

Here is my regex:

```
(\({2}.+?\){2})(?: (?:or) (\({2}.+?\){2}))+
```

The first part of my regex `(\({2}.+?\){2})` match all groups between 2 parenthesis when I use it alone. But when I added the second part to match all groups separated by 'or' `(?:or) (\({2}.+?\){2}))+` it does not work - It seems match the text below which is inadequate:

`((a and b) and not (c and d)) and ((a and b) and not (c and d))`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You may try `(\(\(.*?\)\))(?:\h+or\h+|$)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my problem is about 'or' operator I need to match all the  string then capture groups. IF the whole text is not matched there is no need to get groups.

Comment: it did not work + it gives 3 matches and one group while what I need is to get 1 match and capture the three groups (separated by 'or' thing that is not taken into account in your proposition).Thank you anyway

Comment: You probably aren't aware that you cannot get repeated groups separately. Do read about it.

Comment: Yes you're right but how can we match only the text without capturing groups ? did you have any idea. Thank you for your help

Comment: See this demo: https://regex101.com/r/lNXTnc/1 I have these capture group without `or`

Comment: I can capture the three groups with this : regex101.com/r/Z3o97U/1  but What I want is also to validate that all the text is valid and contain or operator between groups.

Comment: I want to get something like that : if (text is valid) then get all groups. A valid text is a text that contains groups separated by 'or' operator. If we have 'and' operator between the groups then the text is not valide you can see my demo. regex101.com/r/Z3o97U/1

Comment: I split the issue on 2 levels.  - The fist level consists of validating the text with this regex: (?:\((?:\([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+\)|\([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+\) and not \([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+\))\)(?: or (?:\((?:\([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+\)|\([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+\) and not \([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+\))\)))+) and the second level consists of capturing groups with  (\({2}.+?\){2}) (using matcher in java). Thank you Mr Anubhava for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split the issue on 2 levels.

- The fist level consists of validating the text with this regex:

`(?:((?:([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+)|([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+) and not ([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+)))(?: or (?:((?:([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+)|([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+) and not ([A-Za-z0-9-: ]+)))))+)`

- The second level consists of capturing groups with `(({2}.+?){2})` (using matcher in java).
  Thank you Mr @Anubhava for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex in Java:

```sh
(?:^|(?!^)\G\h+or\h+)(\(\((?:(?!\)\)).)++\)\))(?=(?:\h+or\h+\(\((?:(?!\)\)).)++\)\))*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cWT9j7/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `^`: Match start position
  - `|`: OR
  - `\G\h+or\h+`: Starting from end of previous match, match `or` surrounded with 1+ whitespaces
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(`: Start capture group #1
- `\(\(`: Match starting `((`

  - `(?:(?!\)\)).)++`: Match 1+ of any character as long as it doesn't have `))` ahead. `++` is possessive quantifier
  - `\)\)`: Match ending `))`
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `(?=\h+or\h+|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have an `or` surrounded with spaces or end of string

Comment: I thank you for all the effort you make to help me. My goal is to validate this text (this string): ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and then capture groups. So with the regular expression you offered me does not do the validation step. In other words 'myString'.matches("(?:^|\\G\\h+or\\h+)(\\(\\((?:(?!\\)\\)).)++\\)\\))(?=\\h+or\\h+|$)") gives me False.

Comment: You're mistaken. Above regex does validate: `((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d))` as you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/XhhbLx/1

Comment: it matches three parts not one, when i go through java using mystring.match (your regex) it gives me false. I think it's because your regex is giving 3 matches and not just one. While I am looking to have 1 single match but capture several groups (which is in parentheses). I did it in two parts because it seems like there is no other way to do it.

Comment: That 2 parts is supper inefficient approach esp if input is a big string. This regex that I have provided is not for `.match`. You have to use it with `Pattern` and `Matcher` and `.find()` method. There is a sample Java code in the link I have provided.

Comment: So your regex it only serves to extract groups even if the text is not valid like string= `Stackoverflow and (JAVA) ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and blabala and ()) ) ( ssss)`. My goal is to validate the text format before extracting the groups my 2 levels are used for that.The result of your regex with Matcher will return:
`((a and b) and not (c and d))`
` or ((a and b) and not (c and d))`
` or ((a and b) and not (c and d))`
` or ((a and b) and not (c and d))`
So it requires reprocessing.

Comment: You're mistaken again. My regex doesn't even match **`Stackoverflow and (JAVA) ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and blabala and ()) ) ( ssss)`** Check online demo I provided

Comment: Also check my regex for most strict validation and matching

Comment: Sorry, its: `Stackoverflow and (JAVA) ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and blabala and ()) ) ( ssss)`    `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\G\\h+or\\h+)(\\(\\((?:(?!\\)\\)).)++\\)\\))(?=\\h+or\\h+|$)");
  
  String text = "((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) or ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and ((a and b) and not (c and d)) and blabala and ()) ) ( ssss)";
  
  
  Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
  
  while(m.find()) {
   
   System.out.println(m.group());
  }`

Comment: I invite you to test your regex in java.

Comment: Check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/4FElGg/1 your string is not matching

Answer (score 0):

Using two patterns:

- group Pattern: `((\()|(|\) and|\) or|\))|([a-z ]+)))`

  - group 1: open your deep
  - group 2: close your deep
  - group 3: spec

    - spec Pattern: `((?: )(a|b|c) (and|or|))`

      - group 1: sentence
      - group 2: operator